# Accidentally moved all directories under / to the same directory

Tags: files, mv

I ran:
    `for file in /*; do mv "$file" old; done`,
forgetting to put the `.` before `/*`.

I read that open processes might have the inode stored somewhere.  Is it possible to recover my directory structure?

The file explorer is still open, and I am still able to traverse directories.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the file explorer to copy the `old/` in my current directory to `/bin`.  Since the terminal commands failed to run after `/bin` had moved, I was still able to use the open program in `/usr/bin` to recover.